# Root system automorphisms as inner automorphisms of extended Chevalley group

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, automorphism-groups, root-systems, weyl-group

For each automorphism $\sigma$ of a root system $\Phi$ there is a unique automorphism of the Chevalley group $G(\Phi,R)$ such that $\sigma(x_\alpha(t))=x_{\sigma\alpha}(t')$. While conjugating by certain elements of the torus normalizer realizes the action of the Weyl group of $\Phi$, the automorphisms corresponding to the symmetries of the Dynkin diagram are not inner. However, it is sometimes possible to realize them as inner automorphisms of certain *extended* groups, e.g. $O_{2n}$ for $SO_{2n}$ (edit: none for $SL$). It can be seen explicitly in matrices for the above cases, but when working with the group of type $\mathsf{E}_6$, it becomes difficult to work with matrices. So I wonder if there is an invariant description?

There is a general construction for extended groups, see [Berman, Moody, Extensions of Chevalley groups. Israel J. Math. 22 (1975), no. 1], but it is not clear, how to describe the desired inner automorphisms in its terms.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123438/finite-order-automorphisms-on-complex-simple-lie-algebras.

Comment: How can the outer automorphism of $SL_n$ be realized as a conjugation inside of $GL_n$?

Comment: @ya-tayr My bad. Indeed, it can not, otherwise the matrix transpose would be inner.

Comment: @Andrei: Your question needs more detail, I think.  The Berman-Moody construction aims mainly to capture the *diagonal* automorphisms of the Chevalley Lie algebra using an "extended" group, but I don't see how the diagram automorphisms would come in.   (I wrote longer comments but realized they weren't enough.)   Anyway, for type $E_6$ you have the "natural" faithful 27-dimensional representation.  But again the extended Berman-Moody group only gives the diagonal automorphisms.

Comment: Clickable paper link:  [Berman and Moody - Extensions of Chevalley groups](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02757272) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=390077)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me rephrase your question.  Fix a representation $\rho: G \to GL(V)$ of the Chevalley group $G$.  You want a criterion for whether there is an element $x \in GL(V)$ so that $\rho(\sigma(g)) = x\rho(g)x^{-1}$ for all $g \in G$.

In your example of $G = SO_{2n}$ and $V$ the natural representation, you can take $\sigma$ to be an outer automorphism of $SO_{2n}$ and $x$ to be an isometry of determinant $-1$.

In case $V$ is irreducible, here is the desired criterion.  Fix a set $\Delta$ of simple roots for the root system $\Phi$ of $G$, and put $\lambda$ for the highest weight of $V$.  Multiplying the given automorphism $\sigma$ of $\Phi$ by an element of the Weyl group (as we may), we can assume that $\sigma(\Delta) = \Delta$ (and $\sigma$ sends dominant weights to dominant weights).  Now the criterion is: *Such an $x$ exists if and only if $\sigma(\lambda) = \lambda$.*

To see this, note that such an $x$ exists if and only if the representations $\rho$ and $\rho \sigma$ are equivalent (definition of equivalent representation), which is true if and only if $\sigma(\lambda) = \lambda$ by the classification of irreducibles in terms of highest weights.

You can express this criterion as an exact sequence of groups, see Proposition 2.2 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.2840).

To go back to the examples that have already been mentioned:

- the natural representation of $SO_{2n}$ has highest weight $\omega_1$ in Bourbaki's numbering, and for $n \ge 5$ this is fixed by the nontrivial automorphism of the Dynkin diagram, so the criterion says you can find an $x$, as you know.  For $n = 4$, the Dynkin diagram has automorphism group $S_3$, but only one of the three transpositions fixes $\omega_1$, so you can find an $x \in GL_8$ realizing that transposition, but not any of the other 4 nontrivial elements of $S_3$.
- the natural representation of $SL_n$ has highest weight $\omega_1$ (viewing $SL_n$ as having type $A_{n-1}$) and this is not fixed by the nontrivial automorphism of the Dynkin diagram for $n \ge 3$, i.e., you cannot write inverse transpose on $SL_n$ as conjugation by an invertible matrix in $GL_n$ for $n \ge 3$. (But for $n = 2$, $SL_n$ has type $A_1$ and there is no outer automorphism of the Dynkin diagram so of course inverse transpose is an inner automorphism.)
- For a minuscule 27-dimensional representation of $E_6$, the highest weight is moved by the nontrivial automorphism $\sigma$ of the Dynkin diagram, so there is no $x$ in $GL_{27}$ that realizes $\sigma$.
- The adjoint representation has highest weight the highest root, which is fixed by every automorphism of the Dynkin diagram.  So for every $\sigma$ there is a corresponding $x$.  (Assume that the characteristic is very good for $G$ so that the adjoint representation is irreducible.)

Comment: This is a much better way to interpret the underlying question.   The notion of "extended group" worked out by Berman-Moody is not helpful here.   (Maybe the special case $D_4$ should also be mentioned?)

Comment: @JimHumphreys: I added D4 to the SO_2n example.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, you can realize an outer automorphism of $E_6$ inside $E_7$ (or an outer automorphism of $SL_n$ inside $SO_{2n}$).