# Dynkin automorphism of $\mathrm{SO}_{2n}$

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $\sigma$ be a Dynkin automorphism of $G=\mathrm{SO}_{2n}$. By definition, $\sigma$ stabilizes a maximal torus $T$ and a Borel subgroup $B$, and preserves a pinning of $G$. My question is how to define this map $\sigma$ explicitly. I have tried
$\sigma:A \mapsto XAX$
where $$X=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Is this $\sigma$ a Dynkin automorphism of $G$? Are there other ways to define such a map $\sigma$?

Comment: Your definition of Dynkin automorphism seems to allow the identity map, so maybe is to completed (it should probably exclude inner automorphisms). Also "are there other ways" is a bit vague and I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Probably you want $A \mapsto X (A^t)^{-1} X$. Conjugation is going to be an *inner* automorphism; you want an *outer* automorphism for the Dynkin automorphism (okay, strictly speaking $X$ is not in $SO_{2n}$, but I still think you need to do more than just conjugate).

Comment: Nevermind, I'm totally wrong: in (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149363/root-system-automorphisms-as-inner-automorphisms-of-extended-chevalley-group) it is claimed that the Dynkin automorphism for $SO_{2n}$ indeed can be realized as an inner automorphism inside $O_{2n}$, like you have done.

Comment: Theorem 5.10 on page 109 of https://math.berkeley.edu/~jawolf/publications.pdf/paper_031.pdf is also a reference for the result you want.

Comment: $\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\DeclareMathOperator\Or{O}$@SamHopkins, indeed in some sense one should not just not be surprised, but expect, to see this outer automorphism realised by conjugation in a naturally occurring larger group:  we have that $\Aut(G) \cong G/Z(G) \rtimes D$, where $D$ is the group of diagram automorphisms, and the other hand that $\Or_{2n} \cong G \rtimes \Z/2\Z$, and it is reasonable to hope that $G \rtimes \Z/2\Z \to G/Z(G) \rtimes D$ is a map over $\Aut(G)$.  Since $\operatorname{Cent}_{\Or_{2n}}(G) = Z(G)$, this hope is realised.

Comment: Yes and I guess at a more elementary level a silly mistake I made was that for orthogonal matrices of course we have $A^t = A^{-1}$.

Comment: @SamHopkins This is true for the compact form, but not for the split one, which the question is about, apparently.

Comment: @Andrei Smolensky    Yes,  the question should be about find an appropriate matrix whose conjugation sending chevellay generators to chevellay generators.  Of course, it also depends on the realization of SO_2n.  The realization,  g^tg=Id  does not seemto be a good one for writing down a chevellay generators.